# Why is my Apache able to 200 serve .php files that include a trailing slash?

Tags: php, apache-2.4

Running Apache 2.4.6 with vhosts and PHP 7.2.34 and just discovered a weird problem.

A valid URL on my vhosts, such as `http://example.com/exists.php` is also able to be served with a trailing slash; e.g. `http://example.com/exists.php/`.

This is only the case if the file being served ends with `.php`, not .html, .txt, etc.

There are no mod_rewrite rules affecting the vhosts. My php.ini looks good.

Any ideas? Normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior. You can also add other trailing slashes or letters like:

- `http://example.com/exists.php/path/to/`
- `http://example.com/exists.php/otherpath`

it's also used by so some PHP frameworks for URL routing without `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Been doing this a long time and still learn something new every day. Thanks.